# Is it possible to have XA transactions (global transactions) without XA drivers?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, transactions, jta

Does anyone knows if it's possible to execute or achieve global transactions without having XA drivers in J2EE environment?

Comment: what would you like to achieve? E.g. rollback non-XA DB transaction in case of rollback in 'Two-Phase commit'?

Comment: I'm trying to call EJB functions from a quartz scheduler job.  Quartz implementation ear is deployed in different server. I need to know if it's possible to call ejb functions including database operations without rise transaction problems. I am not able to use XA drivers and I dont know how wrap or inject datasources properly and keep the transaction.